# SQL Server: Find the number of substring occurrences of converted data

Tags: sql-server

I have a huge amount of data and I want to count the number of occurrence for a certain column. What makes this confusing is that it is not just finding the same value of the column, but only part of it.

My table contains **TimeStamp** in format of (*YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS*), and I want to apply this SQL command only to *YYYY-MM-DD* part and count the number of occurrence of each based on that. For example, if my data are as follows:

```
ID|TimeStamp 
--+--------------------
00|2017-08-31 09:00:00 
01|2017-08-31 11:00:00 
02|2017-08-31 16:30:00 
03|2017-08-31 22:00:00 
04|2017-09-01 09:00:00 
05|2017-09-01 23:40:00 
06|2017-09-02 10:30:00 
07|2017-09-02 13:00:00 
08|2017-09-02 23:00:00
```

then I want my SQL command to output something like

```
TimeStamp  | Occurrences
-----------+------------
2017-08-31 | 4 
2017-09-01 | 2 
2017-09-02 | 3
```

I have been trying to get there from what I have so far but I haven't had luck.

I have this SQL :

```
SELECT 
    TimeStamp, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    myTableName 
GROUP BY 
    TimeStamp
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC      -- to sort the occurrence count
```

but this only counts exactly same timestamps, so this doesn't output what I want it to output. I am also thinking TimeStamp has DateTime type, so I had to convert it to varchar or something first and get the substring of it.

I tried converting the TimeStamp data type to Varchar, and then get the first 10 letters of the string, so

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) TimeStamp 
FROM 
    myTableName
GROUP BY 
   (SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(Varchar, TimeStamp, 120), 10))
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

but this causes an error:

> Error: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(TimeStamp as date), COUNT(*) 
FROM myTableName 
GROUP BY CAST(TimeStamp as date)
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```